# How to make a Video call in Android using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make a Video call using the ACTION_CALL intent, normally it makes a voice call, is there any way we can make a Video call using this?

Comment: Also, how can we know what Data can we enter in a predefined Intent such as Action_call etc using put_extra()

Comment: extras should be listed in this table: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#constants